# Best way to merge an unpredictable number of similar JSONs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to find the best method to combine identical JSON objects, it can be anywhere from 1-20 JSON objects. They will always look like this, with products being the parent, etc. I want to have all of the products from each objects to be merged.

```
{ products:
   [ { sku: 'EXAMPLE SKU',
       brand: 'EXAMPLE BRAND ',
       name: 'EXAMPLE NAME',
       price: 99.99 },
     { sku: 'EXAMPLE SKU',
       brand: 'EXAMPLE BRAND',
       name: 'EXAMPLE NAME',
       price: 99.99 },
...
```

Any ideas on how to do this the best &/ simplest way? I know of some manual ways, but I feel like that may not be adequate or add additional code where not needed. I am using the newest version of Node.

Comment: basically, you're trying to *concat*enate arrays - because each object has a property called products that is an array

Comment: Yes, however I did a test by doing this `results[0].concat(results[1]);` -- And that doesn't provide any results &/ doesn't successfully merge the objects automatically.

Comment: oh, so you'll have identical sku's in different results, and you want to filter out the duplicates? that wasn't clear in the question

Comment: No, I am really sorry. I suck at explaining, you were correct in your first assumption. I think I may be on the right track, I wasn't able to concat the objects because I was trying to concat with the parent `products`, I need to open `products` first then concat. So now all I have to do is find the best way to concat these objects. Would a simple foreach work while populating an existing initially blank JSON? Or would there be a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a variable representing all products. Loop over all the results and append them to the variable using concat.

```
var allProducts = results[0].products;
for (var i=1; i<results.length;i++) {
   allProducts = allProducts.concat(results[i].products);
}
```

Comment: Wait.. Are you trying to filter out duplicates?

Comment: No, haha. This definitely would work. This is kind of the approach I was thinking I had to go. I'll definitely get better at explaining in the future, I don't usually come here. I clarified that info in the OP comments.

Comment: One-liner if that's your thing: `var all_products = results.reduce((acc, r)=> acc.concat(r.products), [])`